# Loaded tensors to model input

Tags: python, tensorflow

I've followed the [evalutating MNIST](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/layers) tutorial and wanted to adapt it to use my own dataset. Using the [inception model](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/inception/inception) I've converted my images to tensors using build_image_data.py and loaded them. Now I can not directly input this data into the .fit function as it says:

> Inputs cannot be tensors. Please provide input_fn.

Here is the relevant code:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

from tensorflow.contrib import learn
from tensorflow.contrib.learn.python.learn.estimators import model_fn as model_fn_lib

import image_processing
import dataset

tf.logging.set_verbosity(tf.logging.INFO)

height = 200
width = 200

def cnn_model_fn(features, labels, mode):
    input_layer = tf.reshape(features, [-1, width, height, 1])

    con
    v1 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=input_layer, filters=32, kernel_size=[5, 5], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool1 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv1, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    conv2 = tf.layers.conv2d(inputs=pool1, filters=64, kernel_size=[5, 5], padding="same", activation=tf.nn.relu)
    pool2 = tf.layers.max_pooling2d(inputs=conv2, pool_size=[2, 2], strides=2)
    pool2_flat = tf.reshape(pool2, [-1, (width/4) * (width/4) * 64])
    dense = tf.layers.dense(inputs=pool2_flat, units=1024, activation=tf.nn.relu)
    dropout = tf.layers.dropout(inputs=dense, rate=0.4, training=mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    logits = tf.layers.dense(inputs=dropout, units=2)

    loss = None
    train_op = None

    if mode != learn.ModeKeys.INFER:
        onehot_labels = tf.one_hot(indices=tf.cast(labels, tf.int32), depth=2)
        loss = tf.losses.softmax_cross_entropy(onehot_labels=onehot_labels, logits=logits)

    if mode == learn.ModeKeys.TRAIN:
        train_op = tf.contrib.layers.optimize_loss(loss=loss, global_step=tf.contrib.framework.get_global_step(), learning_rate=0.001, optimizer="SGD")

    predictions = {
            "classes": tf.argmax(input=logits, axis=1),
            "probabilities": tf.nn.softmax(logits, name="softmax_tensor")
    }

    return model_fn_lib.ModelFnOps(mode=mode, predictions=predictions, loss=loss, train_op=train_op)

def main(unused_argv):
    training_data = dataset.Dataset("train-00000-of-00001", "train")
    validation_data = dataset.Dataset("validation-00000-of-00001", "validation")
    images, labels = image_processing.inputs(training_data)
    vimages, vlabels = image_processing.inputs(validation_data)

    sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
    feature_classifier = learn.SKCompat(learn.Estimator(model_fn=cnn_model_fn, model_dir="/tmp/feature_model"))
    tensors_to_log = {"probabilities": "softmax_tensor"}
    logging_hook = tf.train.LoggingTensorHook(tensors=tensors_to_log, every_n_iter=10)
    feature_classifier.fit(x=images.eval(), y=labels.eval(), batch_size=100, steps=200000, monitors=[logging_hook])
    metrics = {
            "accuracy":
                    learn.MetricSpec(metric_fn=tf.metrics.accuracy, prediction_key="classes"),
    }
    # Evaluate the model and print results
    eval_results = feature_classifier.evaluate(x=vimages.eval(), y=vlabels.eval(), metrics=metrics)
    print(eval_results)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    tf.app.run()
```

I changed the code to be updates from the comments and now it will hang with no output at the feature_classifier.fit(). The only output it gives at the very start is:

> INFO:tensorflow:Using default config.
>   INFO:tensorflow:Using config: {'_save_checkpoints_steps': None, '_tf_config': gpu_options {
>     per_process_gpu_memory_fraction: 1
>   }
>   , '_tf_random_seed': None, '_keep_checkpoint_max': 5, '_num_ps_replicas': 0, '_master': '', '_is_chief': True, '_keep_checkpoint_every_n_hours': 10000, '_task_id': 0, '_save_summary_steps': 100, '_task_type': None, '_num_worker_replicas': 0, '_save_checkpoints_secs': 600, '_evaluation_master': '', '_cluster_spec': , '_environment': 'local', '_model_dir': None}

**EDIT**:
Changed the code example to the full source code of the program. Instead of using a custom function to convert the dataset to images I now use the dataset and image_processing from the Google inception model. There are no errors, but the program just freezes when feature_classifier.fit() is called. No CPU usage, no output whatsoever.

Comment: I think your vimage,vlabel are tensors. It should be numpy arrays, I guess. is it right ? You can convert them by evaluating them. variable.eval()

Comment: @hars I did and now it just hangs at feature_classifier.fit() doing nothing. No output whatsoever and no cpu usage.

Comment: Would you please post your updated code ?

Comment: @hars I updated the post and added a note at the bottom.

Comment: I might have confused you. I tolf you to do eval() or sess.run(variable) to see you're getting right data.  Did this work : 'feature_classifier.fit(images, labels.eval, batch_size=100, steps=200000, monitors=[logging_hook])'

Comment: Also, your references [1] and [2] are not linked here. Please provide those links too.

Comment: @hars I updated my post and tried your suggestion (in the code above) but it didn't work, same symptons. Could it be that it is somehow trying to use my gpu, but since it's an AMD gpu that it freezes? The "default config" settings it outputs says something about gpus.

Comment: did you try to run it in pure CPU mode ?? did MNIST example run on your pc ?

Comment: @hars I tried running it in pure CPU mode with a ConfigProto, but this did not solve the problem. The MNIST example runs fine and immediatly starts using high cpu and outputting.